# Linked List Explanation

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to C, i am trying to learn linked lists, can some one explain me the code below.
I understand some part of it but not all of it.

```
void deletefrombeginning( node **head, node **tail)
{
  node *temp;
  if(*head==NULL)
    return;
  temp=*head;
  if(*head==*tail) 
            *head=*tail=NULL;
  else
      {
          (temp->next)->prev=NULL;  <-- there is where i get lost.
          *head=temp->next;
       }
        free(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(temp->next)->prev=NULL;
```

This line is making the prev pointer of what will be your new head NULL. So that when the second item in your linked list becomes the new head with:

```
*head = temp->next;
```

it has no prev pointer and is therefore the new head.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
             ------              ------         
            |      | <--prev--- |      |
NULL <----- | temp |            | node | -----> ...
            |      | ---next--> |      |
             ------              ------
```

---

**Short answer:**

- `(temp->next)->prev=NULL;` makes sure that `node->prev` doesn't
  access invalid memory.
- `*head=temp->next;` makes `temp` the new head of the list.

---

**Long answer:**

- You are currently at `temp`.
- You cannot delete `temp` first because you then would have broken links (what would `node->prev` point to?).
- This means you have to first remove the links related to `temp`.
- Since `temp` is the first node, `temp->prev` should point to `NULL`.
- So `(temp->next)->prev=NULL;`  is equivalent to `node->prev = NULL;`.
- We cannot directly do `node->prev = NULL;` because we do not know `node` exists at this point.
- `*head=temp->next` makes sure that the new list head is `node` (in my above ascii demonstration).
- The next step then frees the memory used by `temp`.

---

**Tip:** In case you're nitpicky like me, you might want to assign `temp` to `NULL` right after you free it. This makes sure that you can never mistakenly access `temp` in the rest of your code. Memory can still be accessed in error even after freeing it.